# How can i access Active Record fields in yii2 framework?

Tags: yii2

I made search box using active record in yii2. when i search something it shows the result in a table but i want to access the value of that record out of table.
this is my code in the view:

```
<?= GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'columns' => [

        'Id',
        'Property_title',
        'Price',
        'Address',
        'Size',
        'Construction_year',
        'Street_distance',
        'Description',
        ],
    ]);
?>
```

Comment: Will need more of you code to know what is going on here.

Comment: check this $dataProvider->getModels();

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you have to find model:

```
$id = 1;  // here's your model id
$model = app\models\Model::findOne($id);  // change app\models\Model to your model
```

And then access it like normal object property:

```
$model->id
$model->Property_title
```

Answer (score 0):

first store all result to a variable and loop the results like below

```
<?
$results=$dataProvider->getModels(); 
foreach($results as $result){
?>

<?php echo $result->Id?>

<?}?>
```